# filter system for restaurant booking

Tags: javascript

My script works to 80%. however when it comes to the lower part were you are a couple of 6-8 people my sorting script stops work. I am a beginner and don't know so much. Would be helpful if the problem would be solved.

Q: i want it to work so when you are 8 people you can only pick a table for 8 and above.

LIVE Version: https://elevarbetensys.se/SY15/MS15/GYARB/index.html#reservation

Code:

```
<select id="persons" class="form-group input-group clockpicker form-control selectpicker" style="width:300px;">
                    <option value="1">1 Pers.
                    <option value="2">2 Pers.
                    <option value="3">3 Pers.
                    <option value="4">4 Pers.
                    <option value="5">5 Pers.
                    <option value="6">6 Pers.
                    <option value="7">7 Pers.
                    <option value="8">8 Pers.
                </select>
                <select id="table" class="form-group input-group clockpicker form-control selectpicker" style="width:300px;">
                    <option value="4">Table: 1
                    <option value="8">Table: 2
                    <option value="2">Table: 3
                    <option value="2">Table: 4
                    <option value="2">Table: 5
                    <option value="4">Table: 6
                    <option value="2">Table: 7
                    <option value="2">Table: 8
                    <option value="2">Table: 9
                    <option value="4">Table: 10
                    <option value="6">Table: 11
                    <option value="4">Table: 12
                    <option value="4">Table: 13
                    <option value="4">Table: 14
                    <option value="4">Table: 15
                    <option value="4">Table: 16
                    <option value="2">Table: 17
                    <option value="2">Table: 18
                    <option value="4">Table: 19
                    <option value="4">Table: 20
                    <option value="4">Table: 21
                    <option value="4">Table: 22
                    <option value="6">Table: 23
                    <option value="6">Table: 24
                </select>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#persons").on("change", function () {

    if ($("#persons").val() > 2) {
        //alert($('#table option').size());
        for(i = 0; i < $('#table option').size(); i++) {
            if ($('#table option[value="' +  i + '"]').val() < 3){
                $('#table option[value="' +  i + '"]').remove();
            }
        }
    }

    if ($("#persons").val() > 5) {
        //alert($('#table option').size());
        for(i = 0; i < $('#table option').size(); i++) {
            if ($('#table option[value="' +  i + '"]').val() < 5){
                $('#table option[value="' +  i + '"]').remove();
            }
        }
    }

    if ($("#persons").val() > 6) {
        //alert($('#table option').size());
        for(i = 0; i < $('#table option').size(); i++) {
            if ($('#table option[value="' +  i + '"]').val() < 6){
                $('#table option[value="' +  i + '"]').remove();
            }
        }
    }

    if ($("#persons").val() >= 7) {
        //alert($('#table option').size());
        for(i = 0; i < $('#table option').size(); i++) {
            if ($('#table option[value="' +  i + '"]').val() < 8){
                $('#table option[value="' +  i + '"]').remove();
            }
        }
    }






});
```

});

Comment: my suggestion is you should render table by number of people. E.g : when people select 3 people : you do `renderTable(3);` and just return list of table for 3 people

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you are removing tables that that have less seats than the selected booking.  While this will work what if the user selected eight people accidentally?  If the user then corrected the selection there would still only be table 2 available.  A better way of doing it would be to hide the tables that don't have enough seats -

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#persons").on("change", function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    //Reset the table select
    $("#table").val(0);
    // Hide all tables
    $("#table").find("option").hide();
    // Select all tables then filter the list to those that have enough seats and show them
    $("#table").find("option").filter(function(index, element) {
      return parseInt($(element).attr("value")) >= parseInt($this.val());
    }).show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="persons" class="form-group input-group clockpicker form-control selectpicker" style="width:300px;">
                    <option value="1">1 Pers.</option>
                    <option value="2">2 Pers.</option>
                    <option value="3">3 Pers.</option>
                    <option value="4">4 Pers.</option>
                    <option value="5">5 Pers.</option>
                    <option value="6">6 Pers.</option>
                    <option value="7">7 Pers.</option>
                    <option value="8">8 Pers.</option>
                </select>
<select id="table" class="form-group input-group clockpicker form-control selectpicker" style="width:300px;">
                    <option value="0">No Table Selected</option>
                    <option value="4">Table: 1</option>
                    <option value="8">Table: 2</option>
                    <option value="2">Table: 3</option>
                    <option value="2">Table: 4</option>
                    <option value="2">Table: 5</option>
                    <option value="4">Table: 6</option>
                    <option value="2">Table: 7</option>
                    <option value="2">Table: 8</option>
                    <option value="2">Table: 9</option>
                    <option value="4">Table: 10</option>
                    <option value="6">Table: 11</option>
                    <option value="4">Table: 12</option>
                    <option value="4">Table: 13</option>
                    <option value="4">Table: 14</option>
                    <option value="4">Table: 15</option>
                    <option value="4">Table: 16</option>
                    <option value="2">Table: 17</option>
                    <option value="2">Table: 18</option>
                    <option value="4">Table: 19</option>
                    <option value="4">Table: 20</option>
                    <option value="4">Table: 21</option>
                    <option value="4">Table: 22</option>
                    <option value="6">Table: 23</option>
                    <option value="6">Table: 24</option>
                </select>
```

Comment: Amazing!, thanks for all the help. it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be simplified by not repeating logic. The below code does a few things

1. gets the selected number of people
2. shows all the options
3. finds options which are invalid by using `.filter` on the options
4. hides the invalid options.

```js
$(function(){
    $('#persons').on('change',function(){
      var numPeople = parseInt($(this).val(),10);
      var $options = $('#table option');
      $options.show();
      var $invalidTables = $options.filter(function(){
          return parseInt($(this).attr("value"),10)<numPeople;
      });
      $invalidTables.hide();
      $('#table').val("");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="persons" class="form-group input-group clockpicker form-control selectpicker" style="width:300px;">
    <option value="1">1 Pers.
    <option value="2">2 Pers.
    <option value="3">3 Pers.
    <option value="4">4 Pers.
    <option value="5">5 Pers.
    <option value="6">6 Pers.
    <option value="7">7 Pers.
    <option value="8">8 Pers.
</select>
<select id="table" class="form-group input-group clockpicker form-control selectpicker" style="width:300px;">
    <option value="">
    <option value="4">Table: 1
    <option value="8">Table: 2
    <option value="2">Table: 3
    <option value="2">Table: 4
    <option value="2">Table: 5
    <option value="4">Table: 6
    <option value="2">Table: 7
    <option value="2">Table: 8
    <option value="2">Table: 9
    <option value="4">Table: 10
    <option value="6">Table: 11
    <option value="4">Table: 12
    <option value="4">Table: 13
    <option value="4">Table: 14
    <option value="4">Table: 15
    <option value="4">Table: 16
    <option value="2">Table: 17
    <option value="2">Table: 18
    <option value="4">Table: 19
    <option value="4">Table: 20
    <option value="4">Table: 21
    <option value="4">Table: 22
    <option value="6">Table: 23
    <option value="6">Table: 24
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't remove item, because when they change number of people, the old data were removed and you cannot display those except add it again.
Update: you want to base on then text value? here is a way:

```
$('#person').on('change', function(){
     var numOfPeople = $(this).val();
     var $table = $('#table');

     $.each($table.find('option'),function(){
        var $option = $(this);
        var numb = $option.text().match(/[\d]+/g);
        numb = numb.length ? numb[0] : 0;
        $option.toggle(numb >= numOfPeople);
      });

      //set default value for table
      $table.val(numOfPeople);
});
```

suggestion 2:
  - you should create an attribute that hold the number of table for option, eg:

```
    <select>
       <option people="5" value="2">Table: 5</option>
       <option people="6" value="2">Table: 6</option>
       <option people="7" value="2">Table: 7</option>
       <option people="8" value="4">Table: 8</option>
       <option people="9" value="5">Table: 9</option>
       <option people="10" value="2">Table: 10 </option>
```

then query by people

```
 $('#person').on('change', function(){
     var numOfPeople = $(this).val();
     var $table = $('#table');

     $.each($table.find('option'),function(){
        var $option = $(this);
        var numb = $option.attr('people');
        $option.toggle(numb >= numOfPeople);
      });

      //set default value for table
      $table.val(numOfPeople);
});
```